# CakePHP3&PHPStan: How to remove `undefined method..` model errors when run PHPStan for CakePHP3 app

Tags: phpstan, cakephp3

When run PHPStan for CakePHP3 app, `Call to an undefined method` errors always occurs 
in the lines using [CakePHP3 Dynamic Finders](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#dynamic-finders)

How do I remove errors like dynamic methods?

```
/**
 * @property \App\Model\Table\ArticlesTable $Articles
 */
class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
    public function view($slug = null)
    {
        $article = $this->Articles->findBySlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
        $this->set(compact('article'));
    }
```

```
------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Line   Controller/ArticlesController.php                                           
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  58     Call to an undefined method App\Model\Table\ArticlesTable::findBySlug().    
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept of magic properties and methods is understood by PHPStan with the help of so-called class reflection extensions. [See Docs](https://phpstan.org/developing-extensions/class-reflection-extensions) for more details.